# How Do I Attach A Body To a Delete in Dispatch?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I have a [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) 0.8 DELETE handler that needs to have a body.

So I have a normal DELETE that works fine:

```
def delete = request.DELETE  ># identity
```

I tried this:

```
def delete(body: String) = request.DELETE <<< body ># identity
```

but it turned the request into a PUT because of the <<< operator.

Comment: I found this question because I am facing a similar problem, and the manual (Kelsey cites it below) is pretty cryptic and didn't help. There's a blog post here https://bhudgeons.telegr.am/blog_posts/handling-non-standard-urls-in-dispatch# that does explain how to access the RequestBuilder which is a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with Dispatch 0.8, I used a sort of hacky solution:

```
def delete(body: String) = (request << body).DELETE ># identity
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setBody instead:
"If you wish to supply a string instead of a file, use a setBody method of the RequestBuilder class. Its variants support a number of input types and do not imply a particular HTTP method." from http://dispatch.databinder.net/HTTP+methods+and+parameters.html

Comment: Please give some example code? That comment in the manual is pretty cryptic?